# Iterate through all entries and count a specific value

Tags: templating, array

I am having entries in a Craft channel-section. Each entry has the field "type" with one category filled. I need to iterate through the entries and count the amount of each category.

**Example:**

```
Entry 1, Category: One
Entry 2, Category: One
Entry 3, Category: Two
```

Produces something like

```
One: 2, Two: 1
```

So I know which category is used how often. In any language I would use a key/value set and just increment the amount each time I find the specific category, but that seems to be impossible with Twig in Craft.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before we proceed, let me say that whilst the following will work, I personally think this is a poor use of Twig.

It's far better to collate this information in a simple plugin, rather than jumping through such hoops in your templates.

Caveats dispensed with, here you go:

```
{% set criteria = {
    section: 'exampleSection',
    limit: 20,
    with: ['categoryFieldHandle']
} %}

{% set categories = {} %}
{% set entries = craft.entries(criteria).find() %}

{% for entry in entries %}
    {% set entryCategories = entry.categoryFieldHandle %}
    {% if entryCategories|length %}
        {% for entryCategory in entryCategories %}
            {% set categorySlug = entryCategory.slug %}

            {% if categories[categorySlug] is not defined %}
                {% set categories = categories|merge({
                    (categorySlug): {
                        count: 0,
                        category: entryCategory
                    }
                }) %}
            {% endif %}

            {% set categoryCount = attribute(categories, categorySlug)['count'] + 1 %}

            {% set categories = categories|merge({
                (categorySlug): {
                    count: categoryCount,
                    category: entryCategory
                }
            }) %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% if categories|length %}
    <h2>Category Counts</h2>
    <ul>
        {% for categoryKey, categoryInfo in categories %}
            <li>{{ categoryInfo.category.title }}: {{ categoryInfo.count }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
```

Note that we're [eager loading](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/eager-loading-elements) the categories. Otherwise, we'll end up with N+1 queries.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will look into plugins then and start with this

Comment: Sounds good. You can translate the above approach to PHP pretty easily.